# MongoDb Node.js Driver - findOneAndUpdate() behavior without a field given

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I noticed a strange behavior with the mongodb node.js driver [findOneAndUpate()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)...

I mistakenly gave it just a objectId string....thinking it would default to searching by `_id` field of a document.... so, when I used

```
User.prototype.updatePetArray = function(user, petElement) {
  return this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(user,
    { $push: { pets:  petElement } },
    { returnOriginal: false,
      maxTimeMS: QUERY_TIME});
}
```

it pulled up and modified this document, which does not have this number at all:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d4e2a381c9c28b3056f792"), "username" : "bob123", "location" : "AT", ...}
```

Why did it modify this document when `56d4d35881c9c28b3056f78a` is not in the document?

Answer (score 3):

After I test it following your code with one non-exist `ObjectID`,

```
  var col = db.collection('users');
  col.findOneAndUpdate('56cd129222222', {fname: 'Daved'}, function(err, r) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(r);
    db.close();
  });
```

As a result the first document in the collection was changed .

Per this [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

```
findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback)
```

> `filter`: Specify an *empty document { }* to update the **first document** returned in the collection.

So I think this non-exist `ObjectId` is consider to the same behavior with `{}`

---

After reviewing the source code of [`findAndModify`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.1/lib/collection.js#L2239), eventually, the

```
  // Execute the command
  self.s.db.command(queryObject
```

is invoked, and the `queryObject` is

```
var queryObject = {
     'findandmodify': self.s.name
   , 'query': query
  };
```

So I test `runCommand` in mongo shell with non-exist `ObjectId` as below, as result, the first document is returned.

```
> db.users.runCommand({findandmodify: 'users', query: '123ddae344', update: true
})
{
        "lastErrorObject" : {
                "updatedExisting" : true,
                "n" : 1
        },
        "value" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56c687275d81735019263d1f"),
                "fname" : "Daved"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. It seems to me that this behavior should be changed since it was not exactly empty.

Comment: @dman, I test it with non-exist objectId in mongo shell, it seems the same behavior with `{}` as document said.

Answer (score 1):

The docs keep saying the filter parameter should be an object.

The wrong behavior is likely to some side effect of mis-interpreting the value, being a string not an object (and maybe a truthy value, non-empty string).